# NSXMLParser NSString

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa, nsxmlparser, nsxml

After successfully ( :D) communicating with my server, i'am tying to parse a xml file that it returns me. According to what i'am printing i assume that the parsing is going rather well. The problem is that i'am new, very very very new to NSXMLParser, and don't manage to print it all in little row sections in my device screen on the simulator. i display the rows but they are empty, nothing is displayed in them. if someone who is used to NSXMLParser or anything else could give me advice or show me were it gets messy please:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [stories count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Set up the cell
int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
[cell setText:[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"sizing"]];

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Navigation logic

    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

    NSString * storyLink = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"module"];

    storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"link: %@", storyLink);
     //open in safari
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink]];
}
```

Comment: When you say "put[ting] everything on the screen doesn't work," in what way does it not work? Does it not display everything? Does it display, but in the wrong order? Is the formatting wrong? We need more detail about what's going wrong.

Comment: Sorry i didn't formulate my question well, it doesn't display anything on the screen except the 18 rows needed, but they are empty(i will re-edit my question).

Comment: Generally, you should post new questions rather than adding to the existing one if it's a different topic (such as optimization rather than more problems with the same section of code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're confident that your xml response has been parsed well (and the fact that `[stories count]` returns 18 rows seems atleast something is working correctly)...

try this in your **-cellFOrRowAtIndexPath** instead

```
...
// Set up the cell
NSString *strSizing = [[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                 objectForKey:@"sizing"];
[cell setText:strSizing];
//optional: uncomment the following line
//stories;
//enable breakpoint on this line
return cell;
}
```

when breakpoint activates, check what you get in `strSizing` or simply just check the entire `stories` object to get a better idea.

---

i don't have my xcode near me right now so bear with me and my simple suggestion

Comment: That suggestion was awesome worked right away :D !!! The Breakpoint show were it gets messed up, my index was wrong Thank you very much !!

Comment: great :) in such cases i simply do this... (check the edited answer). anyways, yes, your int variable did look messed up (but i wasn't sure)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, :3 i'am new to objective c. Maybe can i ask a improvement question to push this further ?

Comment: you may, i guess, as long as it doesn't change the context of the original question... in which case it better be posted as a new question (rather than editing this one). refer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask to be in the good-question safe zone. :)